# Jenkins clean workspace directory with paramater

Tags: jenkins, parameters, workspace

I'm trying to delete a specific directory from workspace and using a build parameter, but the directory is not being deleted.  It does delete if I use the literal value.

```
Under
Delete workspace before build starts > Patterns for files to be deleted
Include  **/${WORK_DIR} - Does not work
Include  **/MyDirectoryName - works

I have no problem using ${WORK_DIR} in several other areas in the job.
```

Comment: What kind of plugin did you use? Or just a shell script?

Comment: Workspace Cleanup Plugin

Comment: Looks like someone reported/requested this, but it's marked minor and no one has looked at it since Aug, 2015
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30077